# Транскрипция польского слога « lo » до революции

Tags: транслитерация

Как передавали в царские времена польское буквосочетание « lo »?

Транскипция « ліо » была тогда возможной? Кажется, сегодня пишут « лё », даже в безударных слогах: [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Чему могло бы соответствовать « ліо »?

Спасибо.

Comment: Up to the end of the 19th century using 'io' instead of 'ё' was common.

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаток русско-польской транскрипции, но основным методом передачи иностранных слов до революции была транслитерация. В этом случае, "lo" должно было передаваться как "ло". Подтверждение этому можно найти если в "Яндексе" ввести запрос "Лорентовичъ", первая ссылка будет на книгу 1910 г., где есть следующий текст:

> С о т р у д н и к и— въ Польшѣ: Ст. Жеромскiй (Stefan Zeromski), И. **Ло**рентовичъ (Jan **Lo**rentowicz)

В принципе, несмотря на рекомендации, приведённые в Википедии и ряде других изданий, передача польского "lo" как "ло" по прежнему популярна, связано это прежде всего с тем, что безударная "Ё" нехарактерна для русского языка.

Что касается дореволюционного "iо", то до XIX века эта было обычное сочетание, например у князей Потёмкиных фамилия до конца XVIII века писалась как "Потiомкинъ", впоследствии во всех подобных случаях стали писать через "ё". Единственного иностранца, из тех, что я могу вспомнить, у которого в русском языке появилось "ё", это немецкий поэт Гёте. Во всех остальных случаях как правило используются раздичные сочетания и буквы для замены (*йо, эй, о, е*).

Comment: Если пользоваться буквами « ло », то не различаются « lo » и « ło ». А по-моему это было важно, например, в актах гражданского состояния в царской Польше. В них я несколько раз встречал « ліо » в еврейских именах, и хочу понять чему это соответствует на польском, либо до 1863-го года, когда ещё пользовались польским языком, либо после 1918-го. Что касается буквы « ё », я знаю, что она транскрибирует также французский звук « eu ».

Comment: @Dave, по поводу французского "eu", "ё" транскрибирует только формально, по факту почти всегда фамилии читают через "е".

Что касается гражданских актов, то писали так как придётся. Каких-либо общепринятых орфографических норм вплоть до конца XIX века в русском языке не существовало. Что имел в виду конкретный писец без контекста сказать сложно. Или он имел в виду "лё" (тогда этот знак могли и не признавать), или "lo", или "лио". Можно помотреть какие имена у потомков.

Comment: Я нашел такую транскрипцию фамилии Lorentowicz: ліорентовичъ https://books.google.ca/books?id=0rWcBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA511&ots=B8TZHmLpbV&dq=%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8A&pg=PA511#v=onepage&q=%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%8A&f=false

Comment: @Dave, как я уже писал единой формы не было. Помимо вышеназваных использовали ещё вариант "Льорентовичъ" Справочник 1914 г. http://www.rulit.me/books/rossijskij-medicinskij-spisok-read-387470-210.html

Comment: Там же есть один "Леонтовичъ", два "Лiоренцевича" и "Лопусскiй" из Варшавы